# Junit-spring integration IOException on console

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

When I am hitting spring integration application from my `Junit` class, I am getting below error.

```
12:48:10.854 INFO  [main]
[org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMa
pping] Mapped "{[/getBillServiceImplReq],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=
[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public abstract void 
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.Http
ServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws 
javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException
```

see im running junit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@WebAppConfiguration

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml" })
```

and servlet-context is:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="getBillServiceImplChannel" supported-methods="POST" path="/getBillServiceImplReq" mapped-request-headers="HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL"/>
```

Comment: Please improve your question by adding more details: what code are you running? What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: see im running junit: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) @WebAppConfiguration @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml" })

Comment: and servlet-context is: <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="getBillServiceImplChannel"
  supported-methods="POST" path="/getBillServiceImplReq" mapped-request-headers="HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL"/>

Comment: Please edit your question and include all these details. I'm not good with spring, but other users will help you. Thanks!